# ng-init fails to call a method to the controller from ng-table on load two or more

Tags: html, angularjs, single-page-application

I am using **ng-table** and each row in the table has ng-init which calls a method to it's controller. On selection of a *Shift* drop down table data gets populated and each row calls *getAlltemplates()* using ng-init directive. When I change my *Shift* selection the table data gets populated but *getAlltemplates()* will not be called.

I googled for this issue but I didn't find anything helpful. Kindly help me to fix this.

HTML Code Snippet:

```
<div class="filter-box box-shift">
<span class="filter-label">Shift</span>
<div id="checkOutShift" ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="shifts" selected-model="checkOutShiftSelected" class="selectautocomplete" extra-settings="shiftSettings" events="{onItemSelect:checkOutShiftChange}"></div>
</div>

<table ng-table="checkoutTable" show-filter="true" class="table table-striped">
   <tr ng-repeat="checkout in $data">
       <td data-title="'No'">
           {{ ((checkoutTable.page() - 1) * checkoutTable.count()) + ($index+1) }}
       </td>
       <td data-title="'Template'">
       <div>
        <select ng-attr-id="{{'templates'+((checkoutTable.page() - 1) * checkoutTable.count()) + ($index+1)}}" ng-model="templateSelected[((checkoutTable.page() - 1) * checkoutTable.count()) + ($index+1)]" ng-options="checkoutTemplate.nameEn for checkoutTemplate in equipTemps[(((checkoutTable.page() - 1) * checkoutTable.count()) + ($index+1))]">
             <option value="">Select</option>
        </select>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td data-title="'Operator'">
       <div>
        <select ng-attr-id="{{'operators'+((checkoutTable.page() - 1) * checkoutTable.count()) + ($index+1)}}" ng-model="operatorSelected[((checkoutTable.page() - 1) * checkoutTable.count()) + ($index+1)]" ng-options="operator.firstName+' '+operator.lastName for operator in operators">
            <option value="">Select</option>
        </select>
       </div>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

AngularJs Code Snippet:

```
$scope.checkOutShiftChange = function(){
    //...
    $scope.displayCheckOut();
};

$scope.displayCheckOut = function() {
    //hit the http service and save the response to $scope.checkoutlist
    $scope.checkoutTable = new ngTableParams({
                        page: 1,           // show first page
                        count: 10,         // count per page
                        filter: {
                        },
                        sorting: {
                        }
                }, {    
                        total: $scope.checkoutlist.length, // length of data
                        getData: function($defer, params) {
                                // use build-in angular filter
                                var filteredData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.checkoutlist, params.filter()) : $scope.checkoutlist;
                                var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) : $scope.checkoutlist;
                                params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
                                $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                        }
                });
 };

$scope.getAlltemplates=function(equipType, index, fkTemplateId){
    //method to get the list of templates from a service using equipType, index, fkTemplateId
};
```